# microservice data replication/synchronazation

Tags: message-queue, microservices, event-driven

There’s on point with Microservices I don’t quite get:

Let’s say we have a Microservice architecture which lets users work together on different topics 
The services are running with Event-Driven messaging over a Message broker 
After some time, we find the need to add a Chat functionality which should be able to send messages to users working on the same project. 
We would need in the bounded context of the chat microservice the Users with their Ids and maybe their names also the Projects they are enrolled

So how can we get the Data from the other Microservices in this newly developed microservice? 
Should we switch there to direct calls to the needed microservices owning the data? 
or can we restore the state from the message broker log? 
How are those use cases handled right?

greets

Comment: direct calls to the needed microservices owning the data should be file, why not?

Comment: So, wenn data is no in the db owned by the microservice, we make a direct call to the microservice owning this data?
and what is if hes not available, or data changes, like names? 
or should we always make the call and not cache data in die other micorservice 
When i look on the topic from a DDD view, we need a model of the User and Projects in the Chat Microservice